# Paypal API/ agreement page / hide shipping address block

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have a digital product and therefore want to hide the shipping block.

I use Paypal API CURL [Create agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements_post)

**My CURL post data:**

```
{
"name": "user@user.com Agreement",
"description": "Essential 1  Plan - 19$ trial 7 days - 1$",
"start_date": "2021-11-11T00:52:01Z",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
},
"plan": {
    "id": "P-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
"override_merchant_preferences": {
    "setup_fee": {
        "value": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "return_url": "http://domain.local/membership/checkout/success",
    "cancel_url": "http://domain.local/membership/checkout/cancel",
    "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
    "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
    "max_fail_attempts": 2
}
```

}

I read that I need to set the

> no_shipping => 1

parameter, but I don't know where.

Please help find a solution.

[image]

Comment: That API is deprecated, use Subscriptions instead https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

Comment: @PrestonPHX this doesn`t solve my problem.
but thanks for the comment anyway